# Can I write a LINQ query to parse string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string like this:

```
A00601  CALLE FCO PIETRI   CALLE FRANCISCO PIETRI            A20040407
```

Is there a way to replace this code:

```
foreach (var line in parsedList)
{
     if((line[0] == 'D') && (line[55] == 'Y'))
     {
         item.PostalCode5 = line.Substring(1, 5);
         item.PreferredCityName28 = line.Substring(13,28);
          ...
      }
 }
```

With a LINQ query like this:

```
foreach (var line in parsedList)
{
     item.PostalCode5(line.Substring(1, 5)),
     item.PreferredCityName28(line.Substring(13,28))
     ...
     .Where (line[0] == 'D' &&  line[55] == 'Y')
 }
```

Comment: are those fixed-width columns or delimited by whitespace?

Comment: You could at least show a sample line that starts with `D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
parsedList.Where(line => line[0]== 'D' && line[55] = 'Y')
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(line => {
    item.PostalCode5(line.Substring(1, 5)),
    item.PreferredCityName28(line.Substring(13,28))
  });
```

Which is identical to your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
parsedList
    .Where(line => line[0]== 'D' && line[55] = 'Y')
    .Select(itm => new Item {
        PostalCode5 = line.Substring(1, 5), 
        PreferredCityName28 = line.Substring(13,28)
    });
```